# How do I add subscription cancellation to paypal in future date?

Tags: javascript, meteor, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I am looking for a way to implement future date cancellation to paypal subscription, can't find it in their docs nor anywhere. I want it to work like that so when we have 14 days or less before subscription ends we cannot end the billing cycle this month (we are ending it the next month). It is working normally for cancellation in present time: here is the code so far.

````
    paypal.configure({
      mode: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'sandbox' : 'live',
      client_id: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? paypalConfig.sandboxClientId : paypalConfig.productionClientId,
      client_secret: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? paypalConfig.sandboxSecret : paypalConfig.productionSecret
    });
    const cancelBillingAgreementSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(paypal.billingAgreement.cancel, paypal.billingAgreement);

    const getBillingAgreementSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(paypal.billingAgreement.get, paypal.billingAgreement);
    try {
      const oldBillingAgreement = getBillingAgreementSync(user.billing.paypalBillingAgreementId);
      if (oldBillingAgreement && oldBillingAgreement.state && oldBillingAgreement.state.toLowerCase() === 'active') {
        cancelBillingAgreementSync(user.billing.paypalBillingAgreementId, { note: 'Plan cancellation' });
        if (manual) {
          Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $set: { 'plan.cancelled': true } });
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw new Meteor.Error(err.code || err.type || 500, err.message || err.reason);
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you are integrating the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), billing agreements are not used. Subscriptions will bill according to the Plan you specify.

Subscriptions can always be cancelled by the payer, so you need to bill ahead.  There is no way to "prevent" one from being cancelled during the last 14 days, nor will there ever be any guarantee that the next payment will bill successfully.